# Can't compile GDAL 3.2 on CentOS/RedHat 8

Tags: linux, postgis

I've been trying to compile GDAL 3.2 on CentOS 8 (due to a java project requiring gdal bindings that should be provided by gdal32-java), however rpmbuild fails right at the start before I make any change:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild ../gdal32-3.2.3-1.rhel8.src.rpm
Installing ../gdal32-3.2.3-1.rhel8.src.rpm
error: line 23: Unknown tag: %pgdg_set_gis_variables
```

Note that the source RPM is from the pgdg-source-common repository provided by postgres at `https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/srpms/common/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64`. All dependencies required by the spec file are installed.

The tag `%pgdg_set_gis_variables` in gdal32.spec appears only once (at the line where an error is reported) and seems to initialize some global variables used to retrieve other files/resolve dependencies.

By unpacking the file into `SOURCES` and commenting-out this tag - as well as manually setting the expected values that I see unused, I could get `rpmbuild -ba SOURCES/gdal32.spec`, however it fails at configure, presumably due to missing values that should have been set by `%pgdg_set_gis_variables` (+ In this case, I get an error that shows that there is an attempt to expand the tag despite its being commented-out).

**Do you know where I could find a sample that provides this tag/How I could build this RPM ?**

Comment: It's a macro, not a tag. This may explain why you had trouble searching about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the package `pgdg-srpm-macros` from the PGDG repository to provide their custom RPM macros.

Comment: Thank you. Since posting the question, I did get the spec file to work by installing several postgres rpms but I could not figure out why it made it work. I will try this to minimize the dependencies and install this package in a few days when i can get back this problem.